Is mempool.space Legit or scam
I've been contacted by mempool.space telling me I have a dormant account in their system with 0.91btc and how to reactivate it. They want me to open a crypto wallet such as Coinbase, Binance to transfer the BTC.
My problem is I don't know anything about this account and can't find contact details to varify this company, is it a scam?

This is highly suspicious and very likely a scam. Reputable services like mempool.space do not reach out to individuals about dormant accounts. Do Not Engage.

So to be clear: mempool.space itself appears legitimate, but you were almost certainly not contacted by the real mempool.space.
